# HTTP Error 403: Forbidden when trying to crawl through JSON files

Tags: python, json, web-crawler, urllib, http-status-code-403

I am working on a college project and would really appreciate any help I can get.
I'm working on a piece to open list of SEC .JSON files and save the information into a dataframe so I can extract what I need (such as the exchange listed on and the zip code).
This is my crawl list code.

```
crawl_list_json = []

for CIK in SEC_df['CIK']:
  crawl_list_json.append('https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK' + CIK + '.json')

crawl_list_json
```

and below is my urllib code.
The code works when I test 1 or 2 URLs individually but when I try to create a loop through I get a forbidden error very quickly.

```
pages123 = []

for url in crawl_list_json:
#url = 'https://data.sec.gov/submissions/CIK0001571949.json'

  import urllib.request
  req = urllib.request.Request(
      url, 
      data=None, 
      headers={
          'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/35.0.1916.47 Safari/537.36'
      }
  )

  f = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
  pages123.append(f.read().decode('utf-8'))

pages123
```

Could someone please help me solve this issue as I am quite stuck on it?
I have looked at alot of similar questions on here and using the USER-Agent seems to solve most people issues but not in my case unfortunately. Or am I using it incorrectly?

Please let me know if i can provide more information to help clarify the problem.

Thanks

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue? I'm encountering similar issue.

Comment: I see the same via AWS, sec might block amazon domain for abuse